# importing data with non-standard characters

Tags: r, import

I am importing data with `read.table()`, but some of my column names contain a subscript text (automatically set by the machine that exports the data). R can read the column names fine, but it will come out like this:

```
> df <- read.table(file)
> df
  Col1    Col2    Cт    Cт.Mean
```

When I try to access column "Cт" (`df$CT`), R does not recognize that specific column because I did not type `df$Cт`. Is there a way to work around this so that when I import the data, R can automatically convert non-standard characters into regular text?

Comment: Is this causing a problem? Normally R automatically "sanitizes" the names of the columns, replacing "bad" characters with periods. Perhaps you can be a bit (or a lot) more specific about what's happening and what you would like to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume by "standard characters" you mean ASCII characters. How about if you just converted the values to ASCII values, replacing non-ASCII values with a period. This is possible with

```
names(df) <- iconv(names(df), from="UTF-8",to="ASCII",".")
```

With some sample data

```
a <- c("Col1","Col2","Cт","Cт.Mean")
iconv(a, "UTF-8","ASCII",".")
# [1] "Col1"     "Col2"     "C.."      "C...Mean"
```

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you, that works. Do you know why it replaces each non-ASCII character with two '.' or any other character I choose?

Comment: Many of the non-ASCII characters are actually encoded with two-bytes in UTF-8 and while every ASCII character is a single byte. So it's really splitting the double-byte UTF-8 into two single byte ASCII values. You could use `gsub()` to replace ".." with "." if you like.